# Calculator question involving $\log_2$?

Tags: logarithms, calculator

I have a question, I have a calculator that does $\log$ but I think it does it it in a base ten format for example $\log_{10}(100)=2$ I am wondering how I can solve $\log$ using a base of 2 for example I know $2^7$ is $128$

so $\log_2(128)=7$

Is there any way find $\log$ using base of 2 by hand or some calculator method say I want to find what is $\log(100)$ using a base of two. How can I figure it out because my calculator a ti-83 does not let me.

Comment: Use the [change of base formula](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm).

Comment: Also, I assume you meant to write "$\ln(100)=2$"?

Comment: That's weird; [the TI-83](http://jscustom.theoldcomputer.com/images/manufacturers_systems/Texas-Instruments/TI-83/561268Texas-Instruments-ti83.jpg) has both an $\ln$ key and a $\log$ key, and the inverse functions $\mathrm e^x$ and $10^x$ indicated above the corresponding keys strongly suggest that, as one would expect, the $\ln$ key computes the natural logarithm and the $\log$ key computes the decimal logarithm. Are you sure you're pressing the $\ln$ key and not the $\log$ key?

Comment: Note that $ln$ usually means the natural logarithm with base $e$, and the best way to write logarithms with other bases is to use a subscript such as $log_2$ or $log_{10}$

Comment: Yes I pressed the ln key but I have not used the 10^x one I will try it.

Comment: Notation alert! The "n" in "ln" means specifically that it's the _natural_ logarithm. So writing $\ln(128)=7$ or $\ln(100)=2$ is _never_ correct. In contrast "log" means the logarithm with an implicit base, which can be $2$, $e$ or $10$ depending on the context (different fields have different conventions).

Comment: True, if you want to be absolutely clear, mark the base as an underscript, like $\log_e$ or $\log_{10}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\log_2 x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} = \frac{\log_{10} x}{\log_{10} 2}.
$$
This is sometimes called the "change-of-base formula".

Comment: thanks I did not even know about that formula.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the fact that if you have a logarithm in base $b, \log_b(x)$, then you can convert it to base $a$ by $\frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$.

So, no matter what base your calculator uses, just divide $\ln(128)$ by $\ln(2)$, and you should get 7.